# What is the difference between Quasi static and Dynamic simulation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, terminology, simulations, statics

I'm a newbie in Physics, I read some papers in bio-mechanical that model human joint motion, some of them are modeled using Dynamic, while others using Quasi static. All I know so far is that in Quasi static simulation, it disregards acceleration, meaning a pose is considered as static pose. However, some of those Quasi static papers still consider/mention muscle forces or any other forces in their method. Can someone explain to me the difference in this context? Is quasi static simulation only deal with deformation of an object?

Here are some papers that are mentioned as Quasi static:
[Besier 2005](http://billnordt.com/PATELLOFEMORALJOINT/modelling%20to%20estimate%20cartilage%20stress%20in%20the%20Patellofemoral%20joint.pdf), [Chao 2003](http://rehab.ym.edu.tw/document/vr/cskuo/graphic-based.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In physics, statics is the subset of physical systems for whom all forces balance, i.e., systems that do not accelerate.   Dynamics is the calculation of acceleration.  When you stick the prefix "quasi" onto something, you often mean it is nearly enough that thing that you are choosing to treat it that way.  That's what sounds like is happening here-- you treat the system as though the forces balance, even though you know the system can move.  You are simply neglecting the ma term relative to the individual forces that are getting summed. So yes, you would be more interested in the flexion under the strain of balanced forces, than you are interested in the nonzero acceleration.  A common example of this are explanations of the blue sky, called Rayleigh scattering, which take a quasistatic treatment of the forces on the electrons doing the scattering.

Comment: Can I say that in Quasi static, there is no motion? and it only deals with estimating deformation of an object in a static pose/condition? E.g. let's say I want to calculate contact pressure between 2 objects, I apply forces to both of them, but then I assume they are static and use those forces to calculate the contact pressure between those 2 objects. Am I right?

Comment: Yes to that last bit, but note that static means there is no motion, so quasi-static only means that the motion doesn't matter.  It means the ma term, that comes from the motion, is much less than the forces, so the forces need to almost exactly, but not exactly, cancel.  Imagine lifting a weight very slowly, your arm might bend under the strain,   The bend might be the same as if you just hold the weight in place, or if you slowly raise the weight, so you can analyze the deformation whether the weight is moving or not, it's basically the same.